# Docker desktop for windows: Can't access my container via the browser

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run httpd container 
The ip address is `172.17.0.2` (I'm sure of it cause I've ran `docker container inspect <container_name>`) and I the port is `4400` and when I run the container can't access it via the browser on this address `http://172.17.0.2:4400` !
I've tried to disable the firewall but still the same problem.

This is how I started it:

```
docker container run -d -p 4400:8080 httpd
```

This is what `docker container ls` give me

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
e9f92cfceb76        httpd               "httpd-foreground"   24 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4400->8080/tcp   interesting_wright
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Have you tried without specifying port number?

Comment: @RajuDasupally I must define a port to expose the container am I right ?

Comment: Try your localhost, e.g. `http://172.0.0.1:4400`?

Comment: @DelenaMalan still not working !

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses don't work at all on Windows; there's no reason to look them up.  You should be able to access the service using `http://localhost:4400` (the first port number from your `docker run -p` or Docker Compose `ports:` option).

Comment: If that doesn't work, including an [mcve] would be helpful – explain, in text, in the question itself, how you started the container, with what options, and with what additional configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
docker run -dit --name my-apache-app -p 4400:80 -v "$PWD":/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ httpd:2.4
```

And then user your localhost + that port, and/or the LAN IP + that port.

Reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with **wamp**
when I disabled it I was able to access the container via `http://localhost:4400`

Comment: Was wamp listening on port 4400?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein I know that's weird it's not, yet I can't access localhost:4400 if it's running !

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same problem in windows with XAMPP installed

I resolved it by modifying the hosts file

`/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc`

Just comment on the xampp IP and in this file you can also see the docker internal IP use it to access the application inside the container